# How to run only one fixture by specifying multiple metadata?

Tags: testcafe, fixtures

I have 2 fixtures with a bunch of tests:

```
 fixture.meta({ app: '1', suite: 'smoke', env: '1' })('A')

 fixture.meta({ app: '1', suite: 'smoke', env: '2' })('B')
```

I would like to only run fixture 'A'.

I am using the following command on the command line: .... `--includeFixtures` `app=1` ,`env=1`. I am still seeing both fixtures A and B being run.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are just using the wrong CLI command. In order to run TestCafe fixtures by specifying additional meta data, you need to use the [--fixture-meta](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--fixture-meta-keyvaluekey2value2) command, which you could use like follows:

```js
testcafe chrome my-tests --fixture-meta app=1,env=1
```